# Update sqlite update specific row

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got sqlite database with three rows 
KEY_ID = "id"; KEY_NAME = "name"; KEY_IMAGE = "image";
my DataBaseHandler.class update code look like this:

```
    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact.getImage());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });

}
```

My code for update only (name) without image:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(
                    SQLiteDemoActivity.this);

            db.updateContact(new Contact(1, "Test", null));

        }
    });
```

This code above it will update the first record (name) to "Test" but delete the image..

i will appreciate your help...

Comment: I can assume, that in the constructor `new Contact(1, "Test", null)` the last arg represents the image, and is `null`. That's why the `ContentValues values` variable also contains `null` for the image key

Comment: `I have got sqlite database with three rows`. **NO**. you have `three` **columns** on each row. And an `indeterminate number` of **rows**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume, that in the constructor `new Contact(1, "Test", null)` the last arg represents the image, and is `null`. That's why the `ContentValues values` variable also contains null for the image key

Comment: The OP did not actually ask a question, but if he had, it would be "How can I update the row while keeping the old image?"